# how to access WSL on Windows Server on AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-subsystem-for-linux

WSL stands for Windows Subsystem for Linux. Is it even available on EC2?

All the guide I found talks about Windows Desktop, not server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of August 2017, [WSL is available on Windows Server insider builds.](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/08/08/windows-subsystem-linux-windows-server/).
Although I haven't tried it, I assume you could start a Windows Server 2016 instance and enable Windows Insider updates.
The installation guide for [installing WSL on Windows Server is here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl/install-on-server)

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/05/amazon-ec2-now-offers-windows-server-version-1709-and-1803-amis/

You can now use 1803 update with support for WLS.